# lambda binding upon call is causing issue in my generated code

Tags: python, lambda, expression-evaluation

As the author of [Pythonizer](https://github.com/snoopyjc/pythonizer), I'm translating some perl code to python that defines a function FETCH in 2 different packages in the same source file, like:

```
package Env;
sub FETCH {...}
package Env::Array;
sub FETCH {...}
```

and my generated code needs to insert a special library call (`perllib.tie_call`) that handles the 'tie' operation at runtime.  Here is a sample of my generated code for the above:

```
builtins.__PACKAGE__ = "Env"
def FETCH(*_args):
    ...
Env.FETCH = lambda *_args, **_kwargs: perllib.tie_call(FETCH, _args, _kwargs)

builtins.__PACKAGE__ = "Env.Array"
def FETCH(*_args):
    ...
Env.Array.FETCH = lambda *_args, **_kwargs: perllib.tie_call(FETCH, _args, _kwargs)
```

What is happening, when I call `Env.FETCH`, it's invoking the second `def FETCH`, as that's the current one defined.  I need to invoke the first `FETCH` for `Env.FETCH` and the second `FETCH` for `Env.Array.FETCH`.  How can I modify my generated code to do that?  In the situation that I don't need to sneak in a `perllib.tie_call`, my generated code is:

```
builtins.__PACKAGE__ = "Env"
def FETCH(*_args):
    ...
Env.FETCH = FETCH

builtins.__PACKAGE__ = "Env.Array"
def FETCH(*_args):
    ...
Env.Array.FETCH = FETCH
```

which works as expected.  With the `lambda`, the evaluation of `FETCH` gets delayed and the last one defined is being picked up.  I need it to pick up the `FETCH` defined just above it instead.

Comment: I don't think you can put a keyword  arg before the positional args, but I like where you are going with this

Comment: it does work, I just don't know if it does what you want, so I deleted it

Comment: `Env.Array_.STORE = lambda *_args, **_kwargs, STORE=STORE: perllib.tie_call(STORE, _args, _kwargs)
                                                 ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: I meant the one I posted, `Env.FETCH = lambda FETCH=FETCH, *_args, **_kwargs: perllib.tie_call(FETCH, _args, _kwargs)` that is syntactically valid, I was not sure if it did what you want

Comment: It doesn't work - not sure why: `Env.FETCH = lambda FETCH=FETCH, *_args, **_kwargs: perllib.tie_call(FETCH, _args, _kwargs)
  File "C:\pythonizer\pythonizer\perllib\__init__.py", line 5050, in tie_call
    return func(*_args, **_kwargs)
TypeError: 'Env' object is not callable`.  Here `func` is the first  argument of tie_call.

Comment: yeah, this is why I thought it would not work, while it does fix your issue with the delayed binding, it is causing some issues with the callers of the lambda, in the `*args` they send, `args[0]` is now assigned to `FETCH` is my guess, sorry I could not be of more help

Comment: That's why tried putting the `FETCH=FETCH` (or `STORE=STORE`) at the end of the argument list, but it gave me a syntax error

Comment: last guess, can you try `Env.FETCH = partial(lambda FETCH, *_args, **_kwargs: perllib.tie_call(FETCH, _args, _kwargs), FETCH=FETCH)` where `partial` is from `functools`? or `Env.FETCH = partial(perllib.tie_call, FETCH=FETCH)`

Comment: That doesn't work either - not sure why - it seems to still be eating the arg passed to FETCH which becomes `self`.  One thing I came up with is `FETCH0 = FETCH` `Env.FETCH = lambda *_args, **_kwargs: perllib.tie_call(FETCH0, _args, _kwargs)`.  Another idea is to generate the code I normally generate for non-tied functions, e.g. `Env.FETCH = FETCH`, then add this code afterwards: `Env.FETCH = lambda *_args, **_kwargs: perllib.tie_call(Env.FETCH, _args, _kwargs)`, but I'm afraid that could do several layers of `tie_call`s.

Comment: I am very much interested in knowing an answer to this, if no one answers this, I am willing to set a bounty

Comment: while I am here, would anything from https://github.com/chrisgrimm/better_partial work for your use case, assuming you are open to a third party library

Comment: Ok - here is another idea - I am the author of perllib, which is the run-time library for Pythonizer.  How about if I write a `perllib.add_tie_call(func)`, then use it like this: `Env.FETCH = perllib.add_tie_call(FETCH)`.  Inside of `add_tie_call` I can create a nested function with `func` bound, then return it.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I figured out how to fix it. Thanks @python_user for helping me brainstorm a solution!!  Since I'm also the author of [perllib](https://pypi.org/project/perllib/), the library for Pythonizer, I added a new function to it `add_tie_call`, defined as follows:

```
def add_tie_call(func):
    """Add a call to _tie_call for functions defined in a tie package"""
    def tie_call_func(*args, **kwargs):
        return _tie_call(func, args, kwargs)
    return tie_call_func
```

Then I changed lambda lines to read:

```
Env.FETCH = perllib.add_tie_call(FETCH)
...
Env.Array.FETCH = perllib.add_tie_call(FETCH)
```

and now my test case passes:

```
$ ./runit -P issue_s304
==================== issue_s304.pl ====================
issue_s304.pl - test passed!
issue_s304.py - test passed!
pythonizer 1 tests PASSED!
```

Comment: glad to have helped, I guess you saved me bounty points